# Why does Google recommend this code for WebView debugging?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

To enable WebView debugging based on the debuggable flag, [Google recommends the following code](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)) {     
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Doesn't this have side effects, since the `&=` operator reassigns the `flag` field? I am assuming the application flags are reduced to `FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` after this call. Why would you want the `&=` operator here instead of `&`?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's a bug in documentation. The code is broken. It does indeed strip out any flags from `ApplicationInfo.flags` other than `FLAG_DEBUGGABLE`. The correct check is `getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE`. This check does not modify the `flags` field.

Answer (score -1):

No, `&=` means `getApplicationInfo().flags = getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` which just sets that flag from `0` to `1`.

It is just like `+=` or `|=` which shortens the expression a bit.

All existing flags will be kept.